# Solr sorting by distance and freshness

Tags: java, solr, lucene, distance

I am using Solr for my mobile applications and it works really well. For now, I use Solr to search for users, sorted by distance. But now I want to boost the results that are fresher and leave the oldest one at the end of the results.

I have a last_active_datetime field in my schema, not multivalued:

```
<field name="last_active_datetime"  type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

How can I sort the results by distance and leave the old results at the end? Before I did this:

```
sort=geodist()asc
```

And now, I am trying this:

```
sort=geodist()asc, last_active_datetime desc
```

But I don't see any difference in the results. Do I have to put a weight to the sorting fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy:

1. in case you are not using it already, use [edismax parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax)
2. now you can weight the score with bf, so boost closer docs, see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch/)
3. and also boost the recent documents, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486963/solr-boost-function-bf-to-increase-score-of-documents-whose-date-is-closest)

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I needed. I was using edismax parser so I just add 2 boosting filters and now it works!